# Navigation in vaadin with parameters

Tags: navigation, parameter-passing, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In my project I have a jpa database connection where I store exercises. I read all exercises from the database and store them into the variable **allExercises**. Afterwards I save the title of each exercise in a button, add them to a box for the GUI and also add a **click listener event** that handles the navigation to the next view. This next view is a **detail view** of the chosen exercise. To know on which exercise I have clicked I want to pass the **id** of the exercise object as a **parameter**. For now I have following code:

```
for(Exercise exercise : allExercises) {
        // create new button with exercise title
        Button bt = new Button(exercise.getTitle());
        // add button to box
        boxExerciseTitle.add(bt);
        // add action event
        bt.addClickListener(e -> UI.getCurrent().navigate(ExerciseDetailView.class, exercise.getId()));
}
```

This code is not working. There is a problem with the ID respectively that the navigate function does not handle this two arguments.

My goal is to read the parameter in the detail view like that:

```
public class ExerciseDetailView extends VerticalLayout implements View{
    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        String myPassedId = event.getParameters();
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I change my code that I can pass the id as a parameter in Vaadin?

Comment: Which vaadin version are you using?

Comment: @KasparScherrer: I am using vaadin version 14

Answer (score 1):

The detail view must implement `HasUrlParameter` and then you get the parameter in the `setParameter` method:

```
@Route(value = "exercise")
public class ExerciseDetailView  extends VerticalLayout
        implements HasUrlParameter<Long> {

    @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event,
                             Long exerciseId) {
        // find the single exercise using the given id
        // Exercise exercise = exerciseRepository.findById(exerciseId);
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-router-url-parameters.html

If the type of `exercise.getId()` is not Long but instead Integer or another Number, then change the type of `HasUrlParameter` accordingly.

Comment: @KasparScherrer Probably but from the question I can't see the type of id. I used String because of this line: String myPassedId = event.getParameters();

Comment: @KasparScherrer Ah ok. I don't know Vaadin < 10 :-)

Comment: If you used `HasUrlParameter<String>`, then you would have to change `.navigate(ExerciseDetailView.class, exercise.getId())` to `.navigate(ExerciseDetailView.class, exercise.getId().toString())` too.

Comment: You still assume that id is Long. It could be of any datatype :-)

Comment: I took the liberty of adding this into the answer. If you disagree, feel free to revert it to your version. I'm deleting all comments here as well :)

Comment: That's ok. Thanks